# Do "all" the values in one group exist in any of the other groups

Tags: r, grouping

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. The first column "Alpha" is a set of values that belong to a grouping. The grouping is identified in column to "Beta".

What i need is a function/loop, what have you, that can iterate through all of the groups of Beta. For each group, I want to see if there is any other group that contains all the values in A of a different group, and remove it.

E.g.
My Table

```
Alpha <- c('fred','bob','tom','julie','tom','fred','fred','julie')
Beta <- c('groupA','groupA','groupA','groupB','groupB','groupB','groupC','groupC')
df <- data.frame(Alpha,Beta)
```

What I want to happen, is to see that GroupC (fred and julie) also exist in GroupB.

So the rule, that **every** value in a particular group has to exist in another group, the other group **can** have more values than just the values from the first, but it cant have some, it has to have all of them.

I'm trying to remove redundant groupings.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way in base R using `by` and `tapply` :

```
all_data <- by(df$Alpha, df$Beta, function(x) 
                tapply(df$Alpha, df$Beta, function(y) all(x %in% y)))

all_data
#df$Beta: groupA
#groupA groupB groupC 
#  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#df$Beta: groupB
#groupA groupB groupC 
# FALSE   TRUE  FALSE 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#df$Beta: groupC
#groupA groupB groupC 
# FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
```

As we can see in `'groupC'` there is a complete match in `'groupB'` so we can ignore `'groupC'`.

```
total <- sapply(all_data, sum)
subset(df, !Beta %in% names(total[total > 1]))

#  Alpha   Beta
#1  fred groupA
#2   bob groupA
#3   tom groupA
#4 julie groupB
#5   tom groupB
#6  fred groupB
```

Comment: I think this may have cracked it...  looks like it works on my prod small sample, let me test it on a bigger set and will come back and upvote the heck out of this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
subset(df, df$Beta %in% df$Beta[grepl(paste0(Reduce(function(x,y){setdiff(x, y)}, 
       split(ordered_df$Alpha, ordered_df$Beta)), collapse = "|"), df$Alpha)])
```

Comment: @Maz Im not entirely sure I understand your question please upvote and accept this answer if it does what you require otherwise Im more then happy to continue helping if you provide additional information.